# What Big5 facets correlate with practical sense?

Tags: personality

Which scientific reports can tell me about Big5 scores correlating with a practical, physical preference?

**Examples**:

**Traits**: Practical, Realistic, Down-to-earth, Athletic, Handy, Prefers hands-on work, Problem solver, Focused on the real world

**Interests**:  Animals, Construction, Driving, Electricity, Hearing, Manual labor, Mechanics, Outdoors, Physical activities, Problem solving, Safety, Seeing, Sensing, Sports, Tangible things, Tasting, Tools, Transportation

Answer (score 4):

As a starting point, you might be interested in studies that have related vocational preferences with personality. In particular, [Holland's model](http://www.careerkey.org/choose-a-career/holland-personality-types.html) of job preferences has been highly studied.

Practical sense sounds a little like the "realistic" dimension in Holland's framework.

Larson et al (2002) report a meta-analysis of the Big 5 and Holland's types.
Based on this meta-analysis, while there were correlations between the Big 5 and other types, there did not appear to be any strong (or even moderate) correlations between the realistic preference and the Big 5:

[image: big5 holland realistic correlations]

Note. based on n > 5,000.

#### References

Larson, L. M., Rottinghaus, P. J., & Borgen, F. H. (2002). Meta-analyses of Big Six interests and Big Five personality factors. Journal of Vocational Behavior, 61(2), 217-239.

Answer (score 1):

**Some claims on personality correlations to physical activity:**
Extraversion is a trait that keeps showing up here.

> "Previous studies examining correlates of **leisure time physical activity** (LTPA) (...)
>   Higher standing on **Activity** and **Discipline** and lower standing on
>   **Assertiveness** predicted greater odds of engaging in LTPA and longer
>   duration of LTPA, and higher standing on **Aesthetics** predicted shorter
>   duration of LTPA. "

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23025299

> "**Extraversion** (r = 0.23), **neuroticism** (r = −0.11) and **conscientiousness** (r = 0.20) were identified as correlates of **physical activity**"

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2577457/

> Evidence shows that aspects of personality are associated with participation in physical activity. We hypothesized that, among adolescents, **behavioral activation (BAS)** and behavioral inhibition (BIS) would be associated with physical fitness (cardiovascular fitness and percent body fat), **enjoyment of exercise**, tolerance of and persistence in high-intensity exercise, and affective response to an acute exercise bout.
>   The BAS(reward) subscale was positively related to **Enjoyment** (r = .44, p < .05).

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2761825/

> **Exercisers** were on average less **anxious** (-0.18 SD), **depressed** (-0.29 SD) and **neurotic** (-0.14 SD), more **extraverted** (+0.32 SD) and were higher in dimensions of **sensation seeking** (from+0.25 SD to+0.47 SD) than non-exercisers.

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16439008/

> Results indicated **emotional instability** had direct effects on overall and **strenuous leisure time exercise** while also having significant (p < 0.05) indirect mediation paths through the **performance-approach** and **avoidance goals**. The **extraversion** and emotional instability models accounted from 15.89% to 29.82% of variance in the various **self-reported exercise** measures.
>   [image]
>   http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2095254612000713